# Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "offer"

Tags: php, symfony

I got a problem when I call my entity Offer
I would like to call the method getApplication() but I got this error
Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "offer".
Someone know how to call entity ? thanks

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Application;
use App\Entity\Offer;
use App\Repository\ApplicationRepository;
use App\Repository\BrandRepository;
use App\Repository\OfferRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * Class OfferController
 * @package App\Controller
 *
 * @Route("/offer", name="offer_")
 */

class OfferController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */

    public function index(ApplicationRepository $applicationRepository, OfferRepository $offerRepository, Offer $offer)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();    
        $offers = $offerRepository->findBy([], ['dateCreation' => 'DESC']);
        $application = $applicationRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $offer->getApplication()]);

        return $this->render('offer/index.html.twig', [
            'offers' =>  $offers,
            'application' => $application,
            'offer' => $offer
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your route `/offer/` doesn't include a _slug_ that [Doctrine can use to infer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#automatically-fetching-objects-paramconverter) the entity that you want to use. Perhaps reconfiguring your route can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entity has a property named *id* that uniquely identifies an Offer, you could leverage param converter and simply add the `{id}` parameter to your URL. More info [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html).

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Application;
use App\Entity\Offer;
use App\Repository\ApplicationRepository;
use App\Repository\BrandRepository;
use App\Repository\OfferRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * Class OfferController
 * @package App\Controller
 *
 * @Route("/offer", name="offer_")
 */

class OfferController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="index")
     */
    public function index(ApplicationRepository $applicationRepository, OfferRepository $offerRepository, Offer $offer)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $offers = $offerRepository->findBy([], ['dateCreation' => 'DESC']);
        $application = $applicationRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $offer->getApplication()]);

        return $this->render('offer/index.html.twig', [
            'offers' =>  $offers,
            'application' => $application,
            'offer' => $offer
        ]);
    }
}
```